# App Crashes Every Time on an unsuccessfull ping C#

Tags: c#

I was developing my first app called Minecraft Wiglet. It pings important minecraft sites and it can start in starup. When I am testing my app it succesfully pinged sites while
I was online but when I was offline the app crashed at the fourth line it said "unhandled pingExpection" I am new in coding so go easy on me :)

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        PingReply pingresult = ping.Send("minecraftturk.com"); //Crashed here
        if (pingresult.Status.ToString() == "Success")
        {
            label5.Text = "Online";
        }
        else if (pingresult.Status.ToString() == "Failure")
        {
            label5.Text = "Offline";
        }

        Ping ping1 = new Ping();
        PingReply pingresult1 = ping.Send("minecraft.net");
        if (pingresult.Status.ToString() == "Success")
        {
            label3.Text = "Online";
        }
        else if (pingresult.Status.ToString() == "Failure")
        {
            label3.Text = "Offline";
        }
        Ping ping2 = new Ping();
        PingReply pingresult2 = ping.Send("www.planetminecraft.com");
        if (pingresult.Status.ToString() == "Success")
        {
            label10.Text = "Online";
        }
        else if (pingresult.Status.ToString() == "Failure")
        {
            label10.Text = "Offline";
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Durum başarıyla güncellendi.");
    }
```

Comment: You need to add some try/catches.

Comment: Please add the exception. Do so by revisiting your question, clicking *Edit*, and pasting the exception into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to catch and handle your exceptions. I'd recommend wrapping your pinging into another method like this:

```
private bool CanPing(string url)
{
    try
    {
        return new Ping().Send(url).Status == IPStatus.Success;
    }
    catch (PingException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can call `CanPing` for each site and it will return true or false while handling the case where the user is offline in just one line, like so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label10.Text = CanPing("www.planetminecraft.com") ? "Online" : "Offline";
    // ...
}
```

You could further encapsulate the above into another method, but that might be overkill.

Comment: Another (unrelated) improvement is to use `Status` as an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipstatus(v=vs.110).aspx), and avoid using `ToString()`.

Comment: Yes app don't crash but when I add label5 = "Online"; to try it becomes an unreachable code

Comment: @asi_turk Don't put the label text code in `CanPing`; put it in the button click handler.